# Share a volume between two replicas. Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a rabbitMQ in my project, and I want the queues on one pod to be on the other and the information on one pod to be shared with the other pod. Is there a way for you to share the same volume and both can read and write? I use GCloud.

Answer (score 1):

GCEPersistentDisk supports only ReadWriteOnce and ReadOnlyMany and not the ReadWriteMany access modes. So, it's not possible to share a volume across two containers in a RW mode. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) is the documentation on the same.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is possible to share a GCEPersistentDisk volume between more than one pod. The [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) says it doesn't support ReadWriteMany mode, however it does support ReadWriteOnce mode. That means if a pod mounts the volume with ReadWriteOnce mode, no other pod can mount it until that pod unmounts the volume. So, this is like a locking mechanism in writing mode. On the other hand, multiple Pods can mount the volume in ReadOnlyMany.

You can review this [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693529/how-to-share-storage-between-kubernetes-pods) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649541/kubernetes-persistent-volume-accessmode) for more information.