# Share persistent volume claim with more than one pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Cant share a PVC with multiple pods in the GCP (with the GCP-CLI)

When I apply the config with `ReadWriteOnce` works at once

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
    name: <name>
    namespace: <namespace>
spec:
    accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
    resources:
    requests:
        storage: 50Gi
```

But with `ReadWriteMany` the status hangs on pending

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it is normal that when you apply the config with **ReadWriteOnce** works at once, that's the rule.

**ReadWriteOnce** is the most common use case for Persistent Disks and works as the default access mode for most applications.

GCE persistent disk do not support **ReadWriteMany** !

[image]
Instead of **ReadWriteMany**, you can just use **ReadOnlyMany.**
More information you can find here: [persistentdisk](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/readonlymany-disks). But as you now result will not be the same as you want.

If you want to share volumes you could try some workarounds:

You can create services.

Your service should look after the data that is related to its area of concern and should allow access to this data to other services via an interface. Multi-service access to data is an anti-pattern akin to global variables in OOP.

If you where looking to write logs, you should have a log service which each service can call with the relevant data it needs to log. Writing directly to a shared disk means that you'd need to update every container if you change your log directory structure or add extra features.

Also try to use `high-performance, fully managed file storage` for applications that require a file system interface and a shared file system.
More information you can find here: [access-fileshare](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares).

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the Kubernetes-Documentation, GCE does not support ReadWriteMany-Storage: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes

Answer (score 0):

There are some options here:

[How to share storage between Kubernetes pods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693529/how-to-share-storage-between-kubernetes-pods)

https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares