# Share storage between worker nodes in Kubernetes?

Tags: linux, kubernetes

Is there  any shared volume solution between  kubernetes worker nodes , like gfs2 .

For example when i create single mysql server with persistent volume , if Worker node(which mysql pod is running on) Fail ,  pod is automatically recreating on other nodes  , but data has losed becouse of first worker node has gone down and  persistent volume was on this failed worker node.

Can i use gfs2 clustered storage on worker node  ?

Comment: Theres a [large number of supported PV backends](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes).  Perhaps one of them works?

Comment: You might find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693529/how-to-share-storage-between-kubernetes-pods but as @robsiemb already mentioned K8s supports a couple of persistent volume backends which support multiple writers like CephFS or Glusterfs. I personally haven't seen a solution with GFS2 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with comments above and posting as a community wiki for future.

Relevant for 1.16 version.
As per official [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes) documentation there is a [list](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) of volumes supported `ReadWriteMany` access mode:

- AzureFile
- CephFS
- Glusterfs
- Quobyte
- NFS
- PortworxVolume

[image]

Suggest you use one of them.